# Where should I put my NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am teaching myself to program by making a simple core-data drill-down app with a `UINavigationController` where you select a grandparent entity to see a `UITableView` of parents, and then select a parent to see children. Whenever the user selects an item, I use properties to hand over the `NSManagedObjectContext` and `NSFetchedResultsController` to the next view. Each view controller is a `UITableViewController`, and they all conform to the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` Protocol.

This works fine, but means every view controller is implementing the delegate methods etc., which seems inefficient.

To make the app simpler, would it be better to have a single `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` that is referenced by all my view controllers? And where would the best place for this be - the app delegate?

Thanks!

**---------------------------EDIT----------------------------**

I'm trying to get GorillaPatch's answer to work below. In my child view, I have this method which is a delegate method for the modal "Adding View Controller":

```
- (void)addingViewController:(AddingViewController *)addingViewController didAdd:(NSString *)itemAdded
{   
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [parent managedObjectContext];
    Child *newChild = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [self.children insertObject:newChild atIndex:0];

    newChild.name = itemAdded;
    newChild.dateStamp = [NSDate date];


    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        // Handle The Error.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And there is the following in the header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Trip *trip;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Checklist *checklist;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *checklists;
```

Comment: Why do you add an entity in a delegate callback? Just add the entity to the managed object context directly in the child view controller. The parent view controller should observe the managed object context for changes which is the default behavior if you use fetched results controllers.

Comment: @GorillaPatch - this is in the Child view controller. It gets called when the user presses 'save' in the pop-up 'Add Child' view.

Comment: But why? Just add your new entity to your MOC in your addChild view controller and observe changes of the MOC anywhere else.

Comment: @GorillaPatch I have just one modal "adding view controller". Whichever view calls it will programmatically change a couple of bits (like the title) and implement its delegate method so it's changing the right thing. That way I've only had to make the Adding View Controller once, rather than having a separate adding view for parent, child, grandchild etc.

Comment: That is fine. Are the children, grandchildren and parent different entities?

Comment: Yes they are all different entities with a to-many cascading relationship.

Comment: Well to be honest, I have to see the bigger picture if it really makes sense to further decouple the viewControllers. A possibility is to set the entity description the addViewController should create and then create it locally. But as I said I would have to have a look at the model first. For now go ahead and get stuff implemented. You can later redesign things if necessary or revert changes using your version control system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a FetchedResultsController instance for each UITableView. The reason is because of the way that the FRC responds to changes of data.You can read about the FRC here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> If you set a delegate for a fetched
>   results controller, the controller
>   registers to receive change
>   notifications from its managed object
>   context. Any change in the context
>   that affects the result set or section
>   information is processed and the
>   results are updated accordingly. The
>   controller notifies the delegate when
>   result objects change location or when
>   sections are modified (see
>   NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate).
>   You typically use these methods to
>   update the display of the table view.

Besides, if you're drilling down as you said, each new child view should be a unique set of data that would not allow you to share the FRC.

Comment: Thanks Hobbes - you weren't the only one with that advice, but I accepted your answer because the detail you gave made me feel more confident about carrying on that way. Great user name, by the way!

Comment: Just to follow up, you should read TechZen's comment further down. He explains that Core Data allows you to traverse -to many relationships using NSSets (aka drilling down). NSFetchedResultsControllers aren't always needed.

Comment: I've managed to get that to work for displaying the data, but so far my code chops haven't been up to changing it. :(

Answer (score 3):

In my humble opinion, definitely no. In general, you need a different `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` implementation for each view, because what you actually do in each delegate method may and will usually differ (unless your application is really simple).

Answer (score 2):

No, you'll probably be better off by writing a base class that implements NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate (which would probably be a UITableViewController subclass) and contains a NSFetchedResultsController instance, and then extending your base class wherever you need it.

If you have multiple levels to drill down to, the most likely scenario is that the only thing that will change among your implementations is the predicate used to obtain your NSFetchedResultsController instance.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you hand over the `NSFetchedResultsController` and the `NSManagedObjectContext` (MOC) to the child or detail view controller? I would strongly suggest *defining a property on the detail view controller*, which is the object you want to show.

For example if you have a list of recipes fetched from CoreData and you tab on a recipe, you would have a detail view controller sliding in which would show the recipe's details. I would suggest implementing it by having a `UIViewController` subclass which has a currentRecipe instance variable. You would then set this instance variable to the recipe which you tabbed in your list and then push the view controller on the stack.

By doing this you would *decouple your user* interface really nicely. This makes this view controller reusable in the whole program.

### Update

Due to our lengthy discussion I would like to provide more material which could be helpful if you want to know more about MVC design patterns and how to implement a drill down navigation on the iPhone.

1. **Sample code:** Have a look at the [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913) which was demoed on WWDC09 and WWDC10 to illustrate how to implement a stack of detail view controllers and how they interact with each other.
2. **WWDC session videos:** there are some WWDC session videos which could be helpful:

   - WWDC10: Session 116 - Model-View-Controller for iPhone OS
   - WWDC09: Session 125 - Effective iPhone App Architecture

Comment: My model is not just `Parent--Child` but `Parent--Child--Grandchild`. So if I just set a simple property for `Child`, how would I then drill down to the `Grandchild` view?

Comment: You access the grandchild property of your child. You do not fetch anything new. If it has a one-to-many relationship you already have a property which is an `NSSet` of the other objects. Remember: **CoreData is not a database.**

Comment: Usually on a drill down design, you would only have a fetched result controller for the top table and then you pass the object represented by the selected row to the next table and so one. In this case, you fetch the Parent entity for its table, the user would select the row and you pass that Parent object to the Child table which would populate itself with the Parent.children relationship set. When the user selected a particular child object, that would be sent to the grandchild table which would populate itself with the Child.grandchildren relationship set. And so on...

Comment: I think I understand - I'd be passing along just the child entity, which would contain the grandchild relationships within it and would not need to be refetched. But what if new grandchildren were created or modified?

Comment: then you would use notifications or delegation to communicate these changes. do NOT set an instance variable for the parent view controller as this would destroy the aim of loose coupling. there is a great WWDC video about that, but I have to look that up.

Comment: it is session 116 of the WWDC10 videos: model view controller. there the whole paradigm is very nicely illustrated.

Comment: @TechZen @GorillaPatch I've followed your advice and removed the `NSFetchedResultsController` from my Child Table View, and instead I'm handing over the Parent object as a property. This works perfectly for *showing* the Children in the table. The problem comes when I want to *add* a new Child while in that view. The user hits the plus button, the modal "Add Child" view pops up, the user types in the name of the new Child and hits save ... and then I'm stuck. I no longer have an `NSFetchedResultsController` to add the Child to my model and update the table for me.

Comment: No you are not stuck, take a look at the header file of a `NSManagedObject`. It has the following instance variable `- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext;`. So just create a new child object and insert it into this managedObjectContext. As your FRC of the parent view listens to change notifications of this managedObjectContext it will get updated automatically.

Comment: @TechZen @GorillaPatch I've edited my question to add the code where I am now - at the moment, when I add something, the table just stays blank.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys - I've gone back to having an NSFetchedResultsController for each tableView (as suggested by Hobbes The Tiger and unforgiven) as I'm more confident getting it to work.

Comment: OK do what you think is best for you, but it could get pretty complicated to change your application when you have such strong dependencies between different part of programs. I have updated my answer with more information how to achieve a better application design and some sample code which illustrates exactly what I have tried to explain.

Comment: Thanks. I do understand the principle of MVC (and I watched S116 as you suggested which was really interesting). My problem is with practically getting it to work. Bear in mind that I picked up my first 'how to program' book at Christmas! If I leave the FRC behind, I can get the child data to display using an NSArray, but I've been struggling with what happens when the user adds and deletes stuff, which I previously had the FRC handling for me.

Comment: I am sorry, I just wanted to help. And it is definitely harder to apply the concepts than just understanding them. That is why I suggest that you take a look at the sample code. There the communication between the view controllers is very nicely implemented. Just keep coding, it also took me quite a while to understand what is better of this design.

Comment: @GorillaPatch Nothing to be sorry for! I seriously appreciate your help - any difficulties come purely from my inexperience! I have looked at the Recipes app, which helped getting the viewing part right, but was less helpful with the editing. From my beginner's point of view, it's a bit too sophisticated so it's hard to work out which bits are relevant. I wish Apple had a dead-simple example app that was just a simple to-many drill-down through 3 layers of tables, with the ability to add an item on each layer. It wouldn't be very sexy, but it would be really helpful as a simplified example.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the previous answers:

The NSFetchedResultsController is part of the controller layer of a Model-View-Controller app design. The name of the design should be Model-Controller-View because the controller mediates between the data model (Core Data in this case) and the view. As such the FRC has to be customized for the needs of each particular tableview whose data it fetches, sorts and manages. It properly belongs in the tableview's datasource delegate which is usually just the tableview controller object.

The design you are contemplating would only work if every single table used the exact same entity with the exact same sort order. In that case, why bother with multiple tables?

Comment: At the moment my app is very simple, so in each view the delegate's code is identical (it just refers to self.fetchedResultsController, self.tableView, etc.). But I understand now from these answers that it may not always be that simple, and that's why I need to have it in each view controller (unless GorillaPatch's idea works out). Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I strongly recommend thinking about your app like the mafia: every view controller works on a need to know basis. That enables reuse of code and a only few dependencies which make redesigning the app hard. That is the underlying reason why the MVC paradigm is so useful.